# How to subset 2 parameters in 1 function

Tags: r, function, subset, data-science

I have a problem i'm attempting to solve and have run into a brick wall. I'm attempting to find the mean of a set of data given specific pollutant names and the ID number. So the code all the way to the for loop I believe works fine. I create a function with 3 arguments, create an empty data.frame and then bind all my files into one variable called "dat".

Now i'm trying to subset this new binded data by "id" and by the specific pollutant name (there's two of them named sulfate and nitrate). As you can see, the code under the for loop is a mess.

In specific, i'm unsure how to subset two parameters/arguments in one "which" function so I tried to make a seperate one for each. I was thinking I could use the median function to find the mean between both

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
   dat <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:332){
     dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files.list[1]))
}

 subset_id <-dat[which(dat[, "id"] ==id) , ]
 subset_poll <-dat[which(dat[, "pollutant"] ==pollutant) , ]
 median(subset_id)
}
```

Here is a photo of what the head/tail data looks like in R.[image]

EDIT1: So I was able to get the function initilized (proper term?) but am getting numerous "undefined columns selected" when I try to run it with input.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID = 1:332) {
 files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
   dat <- data.frame()
   for (i in 1:332) {
   dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[1]))
  }
   subset_id <- dat[which(dat[, "ID"] == ID & dat[, "pollutant"] == 
      pollutant) ]
       median(subset_id[, "pollutant"], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

So that function gets placed into memory just fine, but when I try to input parameters  "pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate", 1:10)" I get the following errors.

```
  Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , "pollutant") : undefined columns selected
 In addition: Warning message:
 In dat[, "ID"] == ID :


 Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , "pollutant") : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: `which(dat[, "id"] == id &  dat[, "pollutant"] == pollutant)`.

Comment: And in the future, please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. Just post the code or data *text*, it's much kinder to everybody else (and typically faster, ymmv).

Comment: BTW: it's really bad practice to repetitively `rbind` frames together like that: it works fine for a few, but if/when you get to higher numbers of frames to do this, you'll find it gets significantly slower with each: you should know that each `rbind` operation is completely copying all data from each, it is *not* just appending the new data to the end of the old data. You're fine with this for now, but if/when you work with larger data, try to remember that this scales poorly.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  thank you for help. I was able to get the dual subset working, but am getting a undefined columns selected error... I updated my main post if you wouldn't mind checking it out.

Comment: Instead of `"pollutant"` isn't it `"sulfate"` or `"nitrate"`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question with some outside help.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, ID = 1:332) {
 files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
 dat <- data.frame()
  for (i in ID) {
   dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
  }

      mean(dat[!is.na(dat[, "ID"]),pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)
 }
```